# updating XML attribute in database

Tags: c#, sql

It's in a stored procedure

```
@myname varchar(50)

UPDATE temp_xmlloc 
SET myxml.modify('replace value of (/name/@id[.="XML"])[1] with "GK" ' ) 
WHERE name = @myname;
```

In place of that `GK` if I need to give `@myname` what should I do?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`sql:variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx):

```
UPDATE  temp_xmlloc 
SET     myxml.modify('replace value of (/name/@id[.="XML"])[1] with sql:variable("@myname") ')
where   name = @myname;
```

Comment: The argument 1 of the XML data type method "modify" must be a string literal.   //I am getting error like this

Comment: I did split the string on two lines so it wouldn't wrap.  Try the new version without the `+` ?